# Deleting Duplicate Records In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following code to delete records that have duplicate personnel_IDs. I might just be overlooking something.

```
DELETE p1 
FROM AR_Personnel p1
INNER JOIN AR_Personnel p2 
WHERE p1.personnel_ID = p2.personnel_ID;
```

Comment: Get top 1 of duplicate I'd and Insert them in temp table variable. Then delete all duplicate and Insert temp table entries back to main table.

Comment: your code deleted all values in my test

Comment: Any delete code should be tested first by using a small data set and replacing the delete with select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this - its very fast (assuming column i1 is the dups):

```
 ; with f1 as (select i1 , row_number() over (partition by i1 order by i1 )  rn from t21)
    delete from f1 where rn > 1
```

This uses a CTE and is probably the most popular current pattern for deleting dups.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using group by to collect all dups

```
select *
-- delete -- ALWAYS test first !!
from   AR_Personnel
where AR_Personnel.PrimaryKeyField not in 
  ( select min(p.PrimaryKeyField)
    from   AR_Personnel p
    group by p.personnel_ID
  )
```

But using a CTE is probably faster